# iOS: QLPreviewController does not preview Pages or Word documents

Tags: ios, swift

I am playing around with `QLPreviewController` but it just does not display preview for Pages and Word (.docx) documents. I am running the app on iOS 13 and Pages is installed if that has any effect..

I can successfully preview PDFs, images.. But not documents. When I filter my `QLPreviewItem`s with `QLPreviewController.canPreview` it filters out those testing documents. According to docs these files should be supported - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quicklook/qlpreviewcontroller

What could be the issue? Files app seems to preview Pages documents just fine albeit only thumbnails.

**EDIT**: Solved. It was pretty silly mistake on my part. I dragged all files to the Xcode but for those documents it did not add them to the target automatically. Since I named my Pages file as "Pages document" it looked like the `QLPreviewController` correctly detected the file type..

Comment: I used QLPreview, so there is no difference between .doc and docx. I can display both. Maybe problem is file.

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir could be, I used Word document generated by Pages. I am going to try another one.